# Adding a header with an image with WordprocessingDocument

Tags: c#, ms-word, header

Hey as the title says I'm trying to make a method in C# with WordprocessingDocument which should add a header with a image in it.
However I've browsed through all solutions I could find and nothing have worked neither have chatGPT. The following is the code I'm trying to use:

```
static void AddHeaderWithImage(WordprocessingDocument doc, string imagePath)
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }
        AddImageToHeader(doc, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
    }

    private static void AddImageToHeader(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
    {
        const int dpi = 96;
        long imageWidthInEmus = 113 * 914400 / dpi;
        long imageHeightInEmus = 73 * 914400 / dpi;
        // Define the reference of the image.
        Drawing element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = imageWidthInEmus, Cy = imageHeightInEmus },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Picture 1"
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                    "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = imageWidthInEmus, Cy = imageHeightInEmus }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                         )
                         { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        Header header = new Header();
        // Create a new header
        HeaderPart headerPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
        // Get Id of the headerPart
        string headerPartId = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(new Run(element));

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
        ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };
        paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
        paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
        header.Append(paragraph1);

        headerPart.Header = header;

        IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            // Delete existing references to headers
            section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
            // Create the new header reference node
            section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId });
        }
    }
```

After I've run this code I get the word doc but the image in the header is just a crossout with could not read image.

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated.